# How to parse GraphQL request string

Tags: graphql, graphql-java

I'm using **springboot+graphql**.

Need to convert GraphQL request string to objects so that I can get the operation name.

**Sample query:**

```
query{
getUser
    (userName:"rahul"){firstName lastName}
getBook
    (userName:"rahul"){name title}
}
```

**Sample mutation**

```
mutation{
addBooks 
    (isn:"145" title: "Core" publisher: "The Ed" authors: "Horstmann" publishedDate: "June 1997" userName: "rahul") 
        {title publishedDate}
}
```

Here I want to get the name of operations such as **getUser**, **getBook** and **addBooks** by parsing the input GraphQL query.

Comment: Why you don't define it as object?

Comment: How can it be defined as objects? I'm fetching the input query from InstrumentationExecutionParameters.getExecutionInput().getQuery() and it is returing a String.

Comment: Use `beginExecutionStrategy` callback instead. `InstrumentationExecutionStrategyParameters#executionStrategyParameters#getFields` will have a map of all fields. But it's important to understand there's NO real difference between the top-level field (like `getUser`) and a subfield, like `firstName `.